# Why does addition "+" of two strings in PHP produce this result?

Tags: php, string

In PHP, `"aaa" + "bbb"` would produce `0`.

I know that to concatenate two strings in PHP, I need to use `.`. But I don't know why does addition `+` of two strings in PHP produce this result?

Comment: I think its caused by dynamic typeing. PHP try to count other types than string because string can not be counted.

Comment: It produces integer `0` not `"000"` because addition forces them to integer type and they evaluate to `0` so `0+0` == `0`.  Try `var_dump("aaa" + "bbb");`

Comment: ^ generates a warning in php version 7.1.0+

Comment: Yes, _Warning: A non-numeric value encountered_

Comment: @AbraCadaver You're right. Sorry the browser cached my old test result.

Comment: Just a tip: the best way to find results of these operation across PHP version is http://3v4l.org.
For your question: https://3v4l.org/WnFjZ

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you use arithmetic operators on non-numbers then PHP casts them to integer type.  PHP is sort of smart, so string `"1"` would be cast to integer `1` and string `"1.0"` would be cast to float, however `"aaa"` would be cast to integer `0`, as well as `"bbb"`.  So both cast to `0` is `0 + 0` which obviously is `0`.

See [PHP: String conversion to numbers](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion).

As of PHP 7.1.0 this generates:

> Warning: A non-numeric value encountered

However, this is fine since they are numeric though not a numeric type (strings):

```
var_dump("1" + "2");
```

Comment: @fyrye: yes but those are not arithmetic http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php they are different http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php